# AngularJS search page in table contents

Tags: angularjs, search, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I'm new to this framework and I have to change some webapp.

There is already something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="catalog-search input input--large input--full" ng-model="search">
```

and

```
<ul class="catalog-list catalog-scroll">
    <li ng-repeat="rodzic in list | groupBy:'styl' | toArray:true | orderBy:!'$key'">
        {{rodzic.$key}}
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="dziecko in rodzic | filter:search | bookmark:search" ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(dziecko)}" ng-click="openItem(dziecko)">
            {{dziecko.rodzina}}&nbsp;
            <b>{{dziecko.page}}</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The above code create table of contents for pdf file.When I type some word in input field searching works fine but I can't search by number,let's say I want to find page number 3.

What should I change to be able to find by page number?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no such problem of searching by numbers.  I put a simplified version of [your code into Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IB1idTingVCGyllCWxR5?p=preview) and I can search by words or numbers - even if the numbers are sometimes numeric values and sometimes strings.

Search on 6 or 7 (which are numeric values) or 3 (which is a string '333'). Both work.

Can you modify [my Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IB1idTingVCGyllCWxR5?p=preview) to show the problem?

Here's my HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" class="catalog-search input input--large input--full" ng-model="search">
  <ul class="catalog-list catalog-scroll">
    <li ng-repeat="rodzic in list">
      {{rodzic.$key}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="dziecko in rodzic | filter:search" ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(dziecko)}" ng-click="openItem(dziecko)">
          {{dziecko.rodzina}}&nbsp;
          <b>{{dziecko.page}}</b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Here's my controller with some mock data which I think simulates yours well enough for this demonstration.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.list = [
    [{
      rodzina: 'This is one',
      page: '111'
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is two',
      page: '222'
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is three',
      page: '333'
    }],
    [{
      rodzina: 'This is four',
      page: '444'
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is five',
      page: '555'
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is six',
      page: 666
    }],
    [{
      rodzina: 'This is seven',
      page: 777
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is eight',
      page: '888'
    }, {
      rodzina: 'This is nine',
      page: '999'
    }],
  ]
});
```